# How to find what is redirecting a site

Tags: wordpress, apache2

A site (wordpress) is running online and redirects all URLs to https. To test some new plugins I wanted to install the site locally. I have downloaded the database backup and the whole public_html folder.

I used the apache's 000 default host for the site, this config has no redirects. After importing the database dump and copying all files to /var/www/html I can access the site but every connection to http://localhost get's redirected to the online site. Deleting browsercache doesn't help. Curl reports a 301 header. After the .htaccess file has been cleared of all 301 redirects to https, curl still shows a 302 header to http://online-version which then gets online redirected to https://

```
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Fri, 05 Apr 2019 23:41:17 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Location: http://online-site
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How can I find what is still inserting 302 headers on my local installation?

Comment: What is your Apache configuration?

Comment: Default 000-default.conf that comes shipped with apache. Unchanged but for ServerName

Answer (score 2):

This redirect can come from 3 - 5 places

1) home and siteurl option in wp_options table:

[image: wp_options table]

2) Can be overwritten in wp-config.php:

[image: wp-config.php]

3) It can be done in .htaccess - you have already eliminated that

4) It can be done in apache vhost configuration or main configuration

5) If apache serves traffic on multiple domains it could also be handled in a redirection plugin, but it your case I assume that this is this is the only domain traffic is going to apache

Comment: It was the multisite setup in wp-config. It sends the 302 Header.